# Why am I getting odd input redirection errors running Cryptmount command remotely?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, filesystems

I'm using [Cryptmount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptmount) to mount an encrypted image hosted by a file (as a virtual image)

So far, I've managed to create the image, mount and unmount it, write and read files against the mount.

However, I'd like to mount it from remote. So I've tried this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "'$1'"
3<<<$1 cryptmount -m backup --passwd-fd 3
```

And then I can invoke it with `mount-bkp.sh <password>`

The problem is this is on a backup server and I'd like to call this script from my laptop, so that I can store the password locally and mount the encrypted file system just before I need it.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
$ ssh -C user@example.com "/home/user/bkp/mount-bkp.sh passwd"
'passwd'
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
e2fsck: need terminal for interactive repairs
```

The file system doesn’t need repairs at all and my impression is the password is passed to some other program, which fails for some reason when I'm sending the command from remote.

Tthe `--passwd-fd` option is what cryptmount uses to get a password from an input different than interactive standard input. Using 0 doesn’t work and yields the same message (even when run from the server), that’s why I suspect there might be some issue with redirections.

Moreover, I’m not sure the Cryptmount project is still alive, I found it in Ubuntu and I like the fact it supports regular user operations, without sudo needs.

The Cryptmount file system is configured this way:

```
backup {
  dev=/home/user/bkp/backup.img
  dir=/home/user/mnt/bkp
  fstype=ext4
  keyfile=/home/user/bkp/backup.key
  keyformat=builtin
  cipher=twofish
}
```

**EDIT**: The [Giacomo's answer below](https://superuser.com/a/1608695/320178) fixed my problem. `nofsck` also allows for using `--passwd-fd 0` and send the password via stdin, which I recommend, since my initial version of the script is less safe (ps -efa exposed the password sent as a command line parameter). The new version of my script is:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
cryptmount -m backup --passwd-fd 0
```

This can be called with: `cat /path/to/password | ssh user@server /home/user/bkp/mount-bkp.sh`

Even better, the security can be improved by replacing the 'cat' part by using some key store, eg, the [macos's keychain](https://blog.koehntopp.info/2017/01/26/command-line-access-to-the-mac-keychain.html)

Comment: Seems like this is a [known issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/cryptmount/support-requests/2/). Have you tried to run the same command with `nofsck`? It would be added to the `backup {}` config like this: ` flags=nofsck`.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 BINGO! Thank you so much! I had tried something similar, but with 'mountoptions=nofsck' didn't work, 'flags' fixed it! If you want, move your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it and give you credits. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great to hear this worked! Posted a more detailed answer with an additional tip: Run the script with an SSH call that uses the `-t` flag like this: `ssh -t -C user@example.com "/home/user/bkp/mount-bkp.sh passwd"
'passwd'`. Read the answer for an explanation of what that does and how it might help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disable the file system check with `nofflags=nofsckck` in `backup {}` config.

I am not familiar with Cryptmount, but doing some poking around online for “[Cryptmount e2fsck](https://sourceforge.net/p/cryptmount/support-requests/2/)” shows that this seems to be a known issue.

Have you tried to run the same command with `nofsck`? It would be added to the `backup {}` config like this:

```
flags=nofsck
```

---

### Another idea: Initiate the SSH connection with `-t`.

And an educated guess on what might necessitate this: If you know what `fsck` does — it checks the file system — then the error message makes sense:

```
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
e2fsck: need terminal for interactive repairs
```

Seems like it needs something a logged in Terminal has that a non-logged in remote connection provides. Knowing that I have another idea you can check. Just have the `-t` flag set for SSH set in your command like this:

```
ssh -t -C user@example.com "/home/user/bkp/mount-bkp.sh passwd
```

That `-t` flag initiates the SSH connection as an interactive terminal TTY connection [as explained here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh):

> `-t`: Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple **-t** options force tty allocation, even if **ssh** has no local tty.

Comment: It seems a bug of cryptmount. with nofsckck, I can use it --passwd-fd and send the password by pipelining the standard input at the remote side, which is safer (command line parameters are listed by ps -efa).

With this fix, it works without -t too.